# Pandas apply returns function instead of value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Puzzling pandas apply behavior

```py
data = {'date_col_1': ['2020-01-24', 
                       '2020-03-24' ],
 
        'date_col_2': ['2017-03-08', 
                       '2020-01-24']}
 
testdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then try to convert the columns to datetime,

```
>>>testdf.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime, axis=0)
0    <function to_datetime at 0x1170c2f80>
1    <function to_datetime at 0x1170c2f80>
dtype: object
```

Why is apply returning function instead of return value ?

`>>>pd.__version__` : 1.5.2

Comment: oops `lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)` <--

Comment: ah I guess I need to do explicitly pass row as arg, I thought lambda handled it. `lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)` did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda isn't necessary. You should use:

```py
testdf.apply(pd.to_datetime, axis=1)
```